# Cygwin compiling error: "this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way"

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compiler-construction, cygwin

I am trying to run Cygwin, and I am running into some problems.  I tried to compile a program that works both on Windows with mingw and on a Unix system, but when I go to compile it through Cygwin:

```
gcc threads.c -o threads
```

I get the error:
*this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way*

And that's it... any ideas what I am forgetting or screwing up? I haven't touched this stuff in about 5 years so I am beyond rusty; thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code for us SO'ers to see why you got the error message? :)

Comment: I see what you did there :P
Anyway - what is producing the error? gcc? or when you run "threads" ? From the way your question is phrased it sounds like the gcc compile step is whats breaking, not your program. In which case it sounds like cygwin is perhaps not installed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means the compiler crashed while trying to build your program.

Most likely this means your Cygwin installation is corrupt or happens to include a broken version of gcc.  Try updating to the current version of Cygwin.  This is doubly the case given that Cygwin 1.7 and the first stable releases of GCC 4 are both recent happenings.  If you're still on Cygwin 1.5 or GCC 3.x, I think there's an excellent chance that upgrading will fix your symptom.

Answer (score 11):

In my case this problem was caused by the fact I didn't have a TEMP environment variable defined in cygwin, try:

```
export TEMP=/tmp
```

If TEMP is already defined make sure the directory is not read only.

Comment: in my case, defining TEMP fixed this issue too

Comment: There's a note about this in ~/.bashrc. I use "export TMPDIR=/tmp"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are compiling threads.c which I would gather has something to do with threads, have you tried this...

```
gcc -L libthreads -o threads threads.c
```

This is telling the `gcc` compiler to include the library threads and link it together.

Or... you could include the switch into the above command line `-mno-cygwin` if you 
don't need the unix-like behaviour.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: No, -L does not give gcc the name of a library to link to your program.  It adds the following parameter to the list of directories it looks at to find such libraries.  You mean -lpthread.  Not that that explains why the compiler is crashing.